# Accessing elements out of a 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I run the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int g[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};

//trying to print the array(y,x)

int x,y;
x=1;
y=1;
printf("element (%d,%d) of array is %d", y,x,g[y][x]);

return 0;
}
```

Most of it runs fine. I get the results g[0][0]=1, g[0][1]=2, g[1][0]=3, g[1][1]=4. But when I try to access elements like g[2][0], i get 2. similarly g[2][1]=1, g[0][2]=3, g[1][2]=1. I would have expected if any of the index was 2, i would get a grabage value. This does happen for (2,2) and for indices 3 and above. But I dont understand how elemnts like g[2][0] are accessed.

Can someone help me understand this? I want to understand this because I want to write a code for periodic boundary conditions where I will need to access the elements outside the array.(I am relatively new to learning C and dont thoroughly understand the pointers and 2d arrays thing.)

Comment: What makes you think that the specified values are not garbage values? Accessing an array out of bounds causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Comment: Also, I don't see a comma between `{1,2}` and `{3,4}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: What you call "garbage" is *indeterminate* (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior) and it isn't necessary an "ugly" value, it could be a seemingly innocent value, like 0.

Comment: _I want to write a code ... where I will need to access the elements outside the array._ Then you need to re-architect your code. If you find yourself _needing_ to invoke undefined behavior something about your code design is very wrong.

Comment: When you provide code samples, you should try to make sure, the code is correct. Here x and y are not declared and there is a missing comma in the array initializer.

Comment: @AndreasWeznel I tried looking at the value of g[2][0] after changing g[1][0] to 30. now g[2][0] prints 30. So im guessing the array is accessing elemensts inside itself.

Comment: @lulle, Oh...I didnt see that. Is it really important though? I thought the code was simple enough that improper syntax wouldnt make that much of a difference. I'll keep this in mind for the next time. Thanks

Comment: @YeetTheorem a) It's just good form. Those mistakes are easy to fix since you get compiler warnings. b) When people want to test/modify/do whatever with you code sample, they can just copy/paste it and don't have to fix a bunch of trivial mistakes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, nothing prevents you from trying to access out of bounds memory. It is undefined behaviour, it may cause an access violation, you may get unexpected garbage data or - the worst case - you get exactly the value you expected.

Also you say

> where I will need to access the elements outside the array

You are *not* allowed to do that, *but* nothing will prevent you from doing so. Doing so by accident leads to all sorts of bugs (see off-by-one), doing it intentionally is a very bad idea.

> g[0][2]=3

Think about what element of the 2D-array you are accessing here.
You are accessing the third element of the first line of of your 2D-array, which maps to the first element of the second line. This won't even cause an access violation, but may still cause bugs.

Comment: This seems like this could be the issue. Could you help me understand a bit about how does one go from g[y][x] to which element of the array is being accessed? I thought if the index was >=2, it would automatically lead to accessing an elemnt outisde array.

Comment: Detail :"nothing prevents you from trying to access out of bounds memory. It is undefined behaviour," contradicts itself a bit.  A  C implementation very well might prevent such access, it might not.  It is UB.  With UB, the behavior is not defined and neither defined is what might not happen.

Comment: Could have worded it better i guess. You can *try* to access out of bounds memory, but the outcome is undefined. 
Re " Could you help me understand a bit...": See YeetTheorem's answer

Answer (score 1):

### grabage value

That's it :)

A value you've just *grabbed* from somewhere.

As long as you stay inside the allocated region, this is OK. You have 4 ints starting at `g`. No pointers.

But `g[2][0]` is beyond the array address. Grabbage!

---

My pointer formula was very wrong. Here a tested version with different alternatives to `g[0][3]` I think this is OK, and you can also choose a middle slice as base, as long as you calculate the max. offset correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int g[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};

int x=3;  // column index too high
int y=0;  // but low row

printf("element (%d,%d) of array is %d\n", y,x,g[y][x]);   // original


printf("same %d\n", *(*(g + y) + x));  // one y is 2 ints, needs nesting

int *g0 = g[0];                        // shortcut to g[0]
printf("same %d\n", *(g0 + x));
printf("same %d\n", g0[x]);            // 1-Dim array

int *g0plus = g0 + x;
printf("same  %d\n", *g0plus);         // 0-Dim array

printf("elements %ld\n", sizeof g/sizeof(int));

printf("one beyond %d\n", g0[x+1]);
return 0;
}
```

This all ("same") prints out the last value "4", also for "elemente".

"One beyond" is **-1677831440**. That is what I call garbage.

Comment: Oh...I get it now. This combined with the other answer makes things clear. Thanks! (also lol)

Comment: I just corrected / added. Didn't catch the g[0][2] vs g[2][0] case at first. Big difference. And if you really want g[0][2], I put some examples. Makes more sense for 10x10x10 arrays or so.